# Soft X-rays and Hard X-rays

Tags: voltage, conventions, definition, x-rays

How to know how much of kilovolts are in soft X-rays, and in hard X-rays? 
(Ex: 80kV is in soft X-rays or hard X-rays?

Answer (score 3):

According to [NASA](https://hesperia.gsfc.nasa.gov/sftheory/xray.htm), “The distinction between hard and soft x-rays is not well defined. Hard x-rays are typically those with energies greater than around 10 keV.” So 80 keV x-rays would be hard.

Comment: Thanks G.Smith. Sorry, But I want to ask 80kV, not 80keV

Comment: What is an 80 kV x-ray? Photons have energy; they do not have voltage.

Answer (score 2):

At 80 keV you are definitely in the hard X-ray region. These are the most energetic characteristic K-shell lines of the heaviest elements.

One way of demarcation is by the experimental techniques. Monochromators and spectrographs of hard x-rays are based on crystal diffraction, for soft x-rays grating diffraction is often more suitable. That is at about a few keV.

There is also a difference in experimental techniques for how to use the x-rays, whether one needs vacuum or not. Below about 5 keV absorption by window materials and by air becomes a problem.

Comment: Thank you Pieter.

Comment: @LanAnhPham You are welcome! If you like it you can "accept" this answer.